# pgpool replication not allowing md5 authentication

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, pgpool

I have installed both pgpool and postgresql via `apt`.

In `pgpool.conf`, I have made the changes necessary to use replication mode, as well as my two postgresql databases (currently all running on the same host).

I am unable to figure out what I need to add to my `pg_hba.conf` files in order to have pgpool connect to them. I keep getting this error

```
createdb: could not connect to database postgres: ERROR:  MD5 authentication 
is unsupported in replication, master-slave and parallel modes.
HINT:  check pg_hba.conf
```

both of my `pg_hba.conf` files look like

```
local   all             postgres                                peer

local   all             all                                     peer
local   all             postgres                                md5

host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5

host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5

local   replication     postgres                                peer
host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
```

and my `pool_hba.conf` looks like

```
local   all         all                               trust
local   all         postgres                          md5
local   all         all                               md5     

host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          trust
```

What am I missing in order to have pgpool connect to my databases?

Comment: You are executing createdb. Please try a simple psql connection first. I went through some issues while trying to set up pgpool with replication and made a note of the debugging process I used - http://www.sraoss.jp/pipermail/pgpool-general/2013-May/001773.html

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your default authentication mode for TCP/IP connections (`host`) is `md5`. So at a guess, you have PgPool connecting over TCP/IP.

Change the auth mode for loopback connections on tcp/ip, or use unix sockets with pgpool (usually by omitting the `host` setting).

If you're still stuck after reading:

[19.1. The pg_hba.conf File](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) and
[Chapter 19. Client Authentication](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/client-authentication.html)

in the PostgreSQL 9.4 documentation, and you can't find answers elsewhere (there are lots of related questions on Stack Overflow), let me know and I'll give you a step by step if I have a chance.

Answer (score 2):

I messed around with this problem for several hours and then finally found the solution.

Read the [pgpool-II FAQ](http://www.pgpool.net/mediawiki/index.php/FAQ) and look at the table:

[image: Referenced Table]

You cannot leave the default entries of trust in pool_hba.conf.  I commented out the trust entries and added my md5 entries.

Answer (score 0):

As an additional check, after ensuring matching MD5 METHODS in pg_hba.conf and pool_hba.conf,

make sure to set

```
 enable_pool_hba = on
```

in pgpool.conf

Answer (score -1):

I was also facing same issue. I just do some setting in pool_hba.conf
and add md5 encrypted password in pcp.confi & pool_passwd file 
after that reload the pool setting and start it again.
After these setting. MY application is working fine.